# Generate service client for 3 services using svcutil

Tags: c#, wcf, webservice-client, svcutil.exe

There are 3 wcf services which is using some classes in common in their data contract but not all. I need to generate service client using svcutil toll for all 3 services with different namespaces for the service information and common classes in separate namespace.

Any help on this will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Just add the services one after another in the URL argument like:

```
svcutil.exe /language:cs /out:MyProxyClass.cs /config:app.config http://localhost/Service1 http://localhost/Service2
```

Comment: Hi Dav, Thanks for your reply. This one will not generate different namespaces